# Binary Tree Max sum level - Better Design?

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, tree, binary-tree

I have written a code for finding level in Binary Tree having max sum of elements. I have a few Questions.

1. Is it a good design ? - I have used 2 queues but the total num of elements both queues store will be less than n. SO I think it should be Ok.
2. Can there be a better design?

   ```
   public class MaxSumLevel {  
   public static int findLevel(BinaryTreeNode root) {      
       Queue mainQ = new Queue();
       Queue tempQ = new Queue();
       int maxlevel = 0;
       int maxVal = 0;
       int tempSum = 0;
       int tempLevel = 0;
       if (root != null) {
           mainQ.enqueue(root);
           maxlevel = 1;
           tempLevel = 1;
           maxVal = root.getData();
       }           
       while ( !mainQ.isEmpty()) {         
           BinaryTreeNode head = (BinaryTreeNode) mainQ.dequeue();
           BinaryTreeNode left = head.getLeft();
           BinaryTreeNode right = head.getRight();
           if (left != null) {
               tempQ.enqueue(left);
               tempSum = tempSum + left.getData();
           }
           if (right != null) {
               tempQ.enqueue(right);
               tempSum = tempSum + right.getData();
           }           
           if (mainQ.isEmpty()) {
               mainQ = tempQ;
               tempQ = new Queue();
               tempLevel ++;
               if (tempSum > maxVal) {
                   maxVal = tempSum;
                   maxlevel = tempLevel;
                   tempSum = 0;
               }               
           }           
       }
       return maxlevel;
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Better fits [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Amit, Looks like Code review has very low user base. Also such kind of Qs do get discussed here. SO i feel this forum is more appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like recursion (note, untested code):

```
public static int maxLevel(BinaryTreeNode tree) {    
    ArrayList<Integer> levels = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    findLevels(tree, 0, levels);
    // now just return the index in levels with the maximal value.
    // bearing in mind that levels could be empty.
}
private static void findLevels(BinaryTreeNode tree, int level,
                                  ArrayList<Integer> levels) {
    if (tree == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (levels.length <= level) {
        levels.add(0);
    }
    levels.set(level, levels.get(level) + tree.getData());
    findLevels(tree.getLeft(), level+1, levels);
    findLevels(tree.getRight(), level+1, levels);
}
```

If I was feeling really mean to the garbage collector, I'd make findLevels return a list of (level, value) pairs and sum over those. That makes a lot more sense in co-routiney sort of languages, though, it'd be weird in java.

Obviously you can take the strategy in the recursive function and do it with an explicit stack of nodes to be processed. The key difference between my way and yours is that mine takes memory proportional to the height of the tree; yours takes memory proportional to its width.

Looking at your code, it seems pretty reasonable for the approach. I'd rename `tempLevel` to `currentLevel`, and I'd be inclined to pull the inner loop out into a function `sumLevel` that takes a queue and returns an int and a queue (except actually the queue would be an argument, because you can only return one value, grrr). But it seems okay as is.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many nodes your trees have and how deep they are. Since you're performing [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth_first_search#Features), your queues will take *O(n)* memory space, which is OK for most applications.

The following solution has *O(l)* space complexity and and *O(n)* time complexity (*l* is the depth of a tree and *n* number of its vertices):

```
public List<Integer> levelsSum(BinaryTreeNode tree) {
    List<Integer> sums = new ArrayList<Integer>()
    levelsSum(tree, sums, 0);
    return sums;
}
protected void levelsSum(BinaryTreeNode tree, List<Integer> levelSums, int level) {
    if (tree == null)
        return;
    // add new element into the list if needed
    if (level.size() <= level)
        levelSums.add(Integer.valueOf(0));
    // add this node's value to the appropriate level
    levelSums.set(level, levelSums.get(level) + tree.getData());
    // process subtrees
    levelSum(tree.getLeft(),  levelSums, level + 1);
    levelSum(tree.getRight(), levelSums, level + 1);
}
```

Now just call `levelsSum` on a tree and scan the returned list to find the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Are You sure that elements will all be non-negative?

I would make it callable like `new MaxSumLevel(root).getLevel()`. Otherwise, what will You  when You have to sometimes return maxSum ?

I would structure this as 2 nested loops:

```
while(!mainQ.isEmpty()){
     while(!mainQ.isEmpty()){
        BinaryTreeNode head = (BinaryTreeNode) mainQ.dequeue();
        BinaryTreeNode left = head.getLeft();
        BinaryTreeNode right = head.getRight();
        if (left != null) {
            tempQ.enqueue(left);
            tempSum = tempSum + left.getData();
        }
        if (right != null) {
            tempQ.enqueue(right);
            tempSum = tempSum + right.getData();
        }
     }
     mainQ = tempQ;
     tempQ = new Queue();
     tempLevel ++;
     if (tempSum > maxVal) {
         maxVal = tempSum;
         maxlevel = tempLevel;
         tempSum = 0;
     }               

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This recursive approach works for me:

```
public int findMaxSumRootLeaf(TreeNode node,int currSum) {
    if(node == null)
        return 0;
    return Math.max(findMaxSumRootLeaf(node.leftChild,currSum)+node.data, findMaxSumRootLeaf(node.rightChild,currSum)+node.data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **represent end of a level** using `null` in the queue and calculating the maximum sum for each level.

```
public int maxLevelSum(BinaryTreeNode root) {
    if (root == null)                 //if empty tree
        return 0;
    else {
        int current_sum = 0;          
        int max_sum = 0;
        Queue<BinaryTreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<BinaryTreeNode>();       //initialize a queue
        queue.offer(root);  //add root in queue
        queue.offer(null);  // null in queue represent end of a level
        while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
            BinaryTreeNode temp = queue.poll();         
            if (temp != null) {
                if (temp.getLeft() != null)                  //if left is not null
                    queue.offer(temp.getLeft());
                if (temp.getRight() != null)
                    queue.offer(temp.getRight());            //if right is not null
                current_sum = current_sum + temp.getData();  //add to level current level sum
            } else {                                         // we reached end of a level
                if (current_sum > max_sum)                   //check if cuurent level sum is greater than max
                    max_sum = current_sum;
                current_sum = 0;                            //make current_sum=0 for new level
                if (!queue.isEmpty())                                  
                    queue.offer(null);                      //completion of a level
            }
        }
        return max_sum;                                     //return the max sum
    }
}
```